# How to flash a JSAPI map graphic only when contained in map extent

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.2, dojo

Using ESRI JSAPI 3.7 I'm flashing a graphic that works fine when the graphic is located within the bounds of the map extent (is visible). However, when you move the map so the graphic is located out of the map extent and try to flash, it throws the following error: "0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: lang.hitch: scope["setStroke"] is null (scope="[object Window]")". Here's the function I'm using. Can someone suggest maybe a way to flash only if the graphic is located onscreen? Thanks in advance!

```
function animateGraphic(graphicFlash) {                       
                   setTimeout(lang.partial(function (animateMe) {
                       var shape = animateMe.getDojoShape();
                       fx.animateStroke({
                           shape: shape,
                           duration: 500,
                           color: { start: "yellow", end: [0,255,255] },
                           width: { start: 25, end: 15 }
                       }).play();
                   }, graphicFlash), 100);
               }
```

Comment: You might want to explain your architecture in a bit more detail. You're obviously close to the problem, and the tags hint at it, but they're a strange mix, so making this explicit might help.

Comment: Looks like I was a little erroneous and have updated my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking if the graphicFlash is within the map extent in the beginning of your function.  Here I reference the map directly, there are cleaner ways to do this, but as an example:

```
if(!map.extent.contains(flashGraphic)) {
    return;
}
```